# Can't store image from SQLite to ImageView

Tags: android, image, sqlite

i have this annoying problem.Im trying to store image from drawable folder to database then retrieve it and set it in `ImageView`, but when i try to store it in the `ImageView` and run it its not changed from the default image that i put in first place, the `ImageView` is gone.
Here is the code for the activity where the ImageView is and the code for the DB handler. MainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maintestImage);
    images();
    img.setImageBitmap(dbHandler.getImageDiet());



    initNewProf();
    initExercises();
}
public void images(){ //get the image from the drawable and store it in the base
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abs)).getBitmap();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] photo = baos.toByteArray();
        dbHandler.saveDiet(photo);
}` DB handler
 public Bitmap getImageDiet(){ //retrive the image from the base
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c =  db.rawQuery("SELECT imagedata FROM "+ TABLE_DIET, null);
    byte[] photo = hexStringToByteArray("e04fd020ea3a6910a2d808002b30309d");
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
          photo=c.getBlob(3);
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(theImage);

}
```

Comment: Are you doing this for testing, or learning purposes? That is, why don't you just set the resource drawable directly on the `ImageView` - `imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abs)`?

Comment: Because I want to get images dynamically from the DB.And i want every object to have image.

Comment: Storing images in a database is not really recommended. If those images are already packaged with your app, then simply use them as resources, like described above. If you mean to retrieve images after installation somehow, then it would be better to store them as files, and save just the paths in the database. If you're dead set on doing what you're doing, then you need to do some debugging that we can't really help you with, because `c.getBlob(3)`, at least, should be throwing an Exception, since you've only one column in your query.

Comment: I should also mention that the `getImageDiet()` method you've posted isn't returning anything, so that won't compile. Please always provide a [mcve] when asking debugging questions.